# Firebase Hosting rewrites not working properly

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I currently have the following configuration:

```
// firebase.json   
{
        "hosting": [
            {
                "rewrites": [{
                    "source": "/articles{,/**}",
                    "destination": "/articles"
                },
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html"
                }]
            }
        ]
 }
```

If I go to `mysite.com/articles/<articleID>` I'm taken to `mysite.com` when I'd expect to be taken to `mysite.com/articles`. What am I doing incorrectly?

[I'm following this documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites)

Comment: Try `"source": "/articles/**"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue after taking the following steps:

1. Change my source from `/articles{,/**}` to `/articles/**`
2. Change my destination from `articles` to `articles.html` which is a valid local file
3. Realize that changes to `firebase.json` don't change the behavior of the Firebase Hosting emulator until it is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two possible causes.

1. You have set hosting as an array instead of an object (although I am not completely sure if that is an issue)
2. Secondly, as you can see in the documentation you shared, just above the heading *Direct requests to a function*, it says that the destination file must exist and as `mysite.com/articles` doesn't evaluate to a local file, it is caught by the second rewrite rule and redirected to index.html.

Comment: #1: The `rewrites` property in `firebase.json` is an array, so this can't be the problem. But your #2 indeed is likely the cause of the problem: since `/articles` is not an existing file, hosting tries the next rule.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen in 1., he didn't mean the rewrites property, he meant the hosting property.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @HelderEsteves. I had completely overlooked that. 

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue. `articles.html` is a valid local file and is in the same directory as `index.html`.

Comment: I do not agree that my solutions is completely incorrect. There  was the fact that `/articles` isn't the right setting as it wasn't pointing to a file. I am glad you were able to find a solution though.